# How best to remotely load RDF:XML to Virtuoso (via http call if possible)?

Tags: curl, sparql, rdf, virtuoso

I have inherited a [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) graph database that is accessed by clients on

```
http://someaddress:8890/sparql
```

This I can clear down remotely by running:

`curl -i --data-urlencode query="CLEAR SILENT GRAPH curl -i --data-urlencode query="CLEAR SILENT GRAPH <http://someaddress:8890/db>" -H "Content-Type: application/sparql-query" -G http://someaddress:8890/sparql`

And test that it's done what I expected with:

`curl -i --data-urlencode query="select (count(?s) as ?count) where { ?s ?p ?o . }" -H "Content-Type: application/sparql-query" -G http://someaddress:8890/sparql`

Which gives me the count of triples in the database - the count is non-zero, but it looks as though the remaining triples are system managed ones.

Next, I have a number of RDF files I want to load, the contents of which I intend to make available to users over the network via a SPARQL endpoint.

So to load the data, I run

`curl -X PUT --digest -u "user:pass" -T "C:\data\rdf\triples_domain_a.rdf" -G "http://someaddress:8890/sparql-graph-crud-auth" --data-urlencode "graph=http://someaddress:8890/db"`

I can see the triples are created when I check the count using the earlier `curl` - and it's gone up by the triple count in this file. So far, so good.

However, when I run the second file in, with:

`curl -X PUT --digest -u "user:pass" -T "C:\data\rdf\triples_domain_b.rdf" -G "http://someaddress:8890/sparql-graph-crud-auth" --data-urlencode "graph=http://someaddress:8890/db"`

Rather than *appending* these triples to my database, it *replaces* the previously loaded content with this one.

I've got a series of additional files to load - what am I doing wrong?

I can do this directly on the `http://someaddress:8890` server by connecting to an isql session and running `RDF_GLOBAL_RESET();` and `DB.DBA.RDF_LOAD_RDFXML_MT` locally - but I'm generating the files from a different server, and ideally, I want that server to upload them to the triplestore itself, without any manual intervention. The `curl` approach is preferred since it's a relatively simple command I can parameterise and execute from the generating server.

It feels as though I'm close, but I can't seem to get past this replacement issue - any ideas?

Comment: I would hazard a guess that you should use `POST` instead of `PUT` if you wish to append rather than replace. I'm not entirely sure if that is the only change you need though.

Comment: My first idea is to raise Virtuoso-specific questions to Virtuoso-focused forums, such as the public [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users), the public [OpenLink Support Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php), or a confidential [OpenLink Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp).  (ObDisclaimer: I work for OpenLink Software, producer of Virtuoso.)

Comment: I think the `curl` command you provided for the `CLEAR` may have a double-paste in it?  Also, I wonder whether you are intending to add this data to the target endpoint's *default graph* or to the *named graph* you appear to be specifying?  The default graph seems more likely, and in this case, dropping the `"graph=..."` clause may resolve your described issue. Also, depending on what tool is generating the RDF/XML, you may find N3, TTL, or other serialization goes easier on your bandwidth.